# How was it anatomically possible for Danaerys to breastfeed her dragons from her breast?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Okay first things first this is not a freaky question, I just thought that the scene of Danaerys "feeding" her dragons was put there for sexual purposes. If I am not mistaken certain animals can't be suckled by certain other animals due to anatomical features, so why was it possible for Danaerys to feed her dragons? Was this possible?

Comment: I'm not VTC since I don't follow GOT, but I'm pretty sure this question will get closed as *primarily opinion-based*. It's up to the author to decide what is possible in his story.

Comment: Dragons are magical creatures. They already show humanlike dietary habits by not eating raw meat, only cooked meat. Theoretically, dragons shouldn't be able to suckle at all since we suppose that they are reptiles, but they are magical.

Comment: Which episode was this in???

Comment: @ash_k29 One in season 2 I think but can't remember which

Comment: I don't know if it was in the TV show I don't watch that, but I know it was in the first or second book of GoT.

Comment: In order to suckle, you need lips and cheeks. Since dragons do not (seem to) have either, that would make suckling difficult. Additionally, reptiles and birds do not breastfeed, as far as I know. But dragons do not exist, so GRRM is free to describe them in whatever way he chooses. As has been mentioned before, a certain suspension of belief is required to read fantasy: If you are ready to accept dragons themselves, breastfeeding dragons should not be all that impossible.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed so quick.  It's possible that GRRM may have answered it in an interview Q&A (like the "Are Targaryens immune to fire?" question) so let's give it time for the possible existence of such an answer to be found.

Comment: Actually you don't need cheeks to suckle, dogs and cats do it by creating suction with their tongue, and platypuses lap.

Comment: @LewDelport Platypuses lap because female platypuses secrete milk from a patch on their skin.  Human females obviously don't do this, so platypuses aren't really a good example.  Cats and Dogs are a good example.  I'd be concerned if dragons are born with teeth like reptiles though.

Comment: After all the things you've seen on this show, this is what strikes as unrealistic to you? We have giants riding wooly mammoths, humanoid ice creatures that can conjure up the dead, sorcerers with real magical powers... But you're hung up on the how mythical fire-breathing creatures can be breastfed?

Comment: @RoyalFlush giants riding mammoths makes sense (Sentient creature domesticating another animal of suitable size for their carrying capability). The walkers resurrecting people and sorcerers are literally explained by magic. Dragons breastfeeding is illogical.

Comment: @Kai - If she was full enough her breasts were leaking, the dragon could lap.

Comment: @cde Dragons are by their very nature magical, so if you're happy with "it's magic" as an explanation (as you clearly are), you can use that to explain _anything_ about dragons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlqTHhdCQko) of ducklings 'nursing' on a foster cat mom might be enlightening (at about 2:45). The natural instinct of ducklings to forage led them to discover that nibbling on the cat's nipples would result in a bit of liquid nutrition. Ducks wouldn't have the ability to digest milk, but presumably they didn't get enough to be harmful.

Comment: "Ducks wouldn't have the ability to digest milk, but presumably they didn't get enough to be harmful." -- they wouldn't be able to digest lactose, the sugar that's the main calorie content of milk and which mammals have evolved a special enzyme to digest, but there's also a bit of fat in milk which would give them at least some calories I think.

Comment: out of curiosity I googled the composition of human milk vs. cat milk -- the chart at http://ansci.illinois.edu/static/ansc438/Lactation/catsdogs.html says that while human milk is 6.8% sugar (lactose) and only 0.8% protein and 4.1% fat, cat milk is only 3.7% sugar but 10.6% protein and 10.8% fat, a big difference which would mean lactose intolerance would be much less of a problem for a duck trying to drink cat milk.

Answer (score 2):

Dragons in mythology and folklore breastfeed baby dragons. Dragons, despite having an overall reptilian appearance, display several mammalian qualities such as mammalian wings, typically mammalian horns or antlers, paw like claws, lion manes, horse manes, whiskers, etc...

They are hybrid magical creatures. In fact, in mythology, many female dragons have human like upper bodies and breasts.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: What's mammalian wings?

Comment: @user13267 basically bat wings, as bats are the only mammals that actually have wings that enable flight.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it was all for "sexual purposes", rather it was driving home the important point that Daenerys is their mother and not just in a figurative manner. Also, later in the story this plot point with her intimate, instinctual bonding with the dragons will help explain why the dragons still respected her even after they grew up to be fearsome apex predators.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! We generally prefer that answers here are backed up with evidence, do you have any that you can [edit] in?